# Why does my code for appending items to masonry give me 'undefined is not a function'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm working on a website that uses masonry to laid out items in a grid.  When the end user clicks a filter on the website, this is the function that gets called.  It is important that I mention right off the bat that the server side code is correct.  What is not correct is my jQuery code below.

```
<script>
function filter(type) {
  $.get("/storefront/?filter="+type, function(data) {
     var $data = data;
     $('.grid').children().remove();
     $('.grid').masonry().append( $data ).masonry( 'appended', $data, true ).masonry( 'layout' );
  });
}
```

When this function is called, the grid disappears, none of the new, filtered data appears and I receive the following error in Chrome Console for the LAST line in the function.

```
uncaught typeerror: undefined is not a function
```

What is strange, and also proof that my server side code is correct is that if I change:

```
$('.grid').masonry().append( $data ).masonry( 'appended', $data, true ).masonry( 'layout' );
```

to this:

```
$('.grid').append( $data );
```

It loads in all the data and it is formatted perfectly other than the entire grid being moved up 100px.

The line of code causing the error is an exact replica of MANY projects that use masonry and have it working, so I don't understand why mine is not, I don't know if it is a simple syntax error or something deeper than that.

As a workaround I tried to just destroy the masonry lay out and initialize a new one but I'm not even sure how to do that because the code to initalize masonry in the first place is actually inside my Animonscroll.js library.  Here is that part of the code (which I'm not able to follow).

```
animonscroll.js

    imagesLoaded( this.el, function() {

    // initialize masonry
    new Masonry( self.el, {
        itemSelector: 'li',

        gutter: 14,
        transitionDuration : 0
    } );

    if( Modernizr.cssanimations ) {
        // the items already shown...
        self.items.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            if( inViewport( el ) ) {
                self._checkTotalRendered();
                classie.add( el, 'shown' );
            }
        } );
```

Comment: are the scripts being properly loaded..??

Answer (score 0):

The error `undefined is not a function` generally happens when you have an object in Javascript that is `undefined`, and you put parenthesis `()` after it, as if you're trying to invoke it like a function.

For example:

```
var a = undefined;
a();    // undefined is not a function
```

Somewhere in your code (it would be much easier to see with a debugger, or if you split up your code into multiple lines), you have an object that evaluates to `undefined`, but you're using it as a function.

Now, to your code - it looks like you've narrowed down the problem to this line that fails:

```
$('.grid').masonry().append( $data ).masonry( 'appended', $data, true ).masonry( 'layout' );
```

and this alternate line that works:

```
$('.grid').append( $data );
```

Based on this, the only things you're evaluating as functions in the failed line is `masonry` and `append` - based on that information, one of these (or something they call internally) is `undefined`.

As another debugging tip, You can also use `console.log` to output information, like `console.log($('.grid').masonry);`, etc. If `masonry` is `undefined`, then it's likely a problem loading that script.

Hope that helps you narrow down your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Also I can rule out append as being the problem since $('.grid').append( $data ); doesn't cause an error, is that right?

Comment: Also, I have masonry working on my website, it is fully functional, the problem only occurs when a filter is clicked.  Given that masonry works on the same page until the filter is clicked, wouldn't that mean the masonry script is loading fine?  I will try using console.log like you said and report back later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are calling masonry() before you append:

```
$('.grid').masonry().append( $data ).masonry( 'appended', $data, true ).masonry( 'layout' );
```

Try this:

```
$('.grid').append( $data ).masonry( 'appended', $data, true ).masonry( 'layout' );
```

Comment: I was trying to follow Desandros response here  https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/613 where he calls masonry() before append.

Comment: I used your example, and it loads the items, but the grid moves 100px up and I still get the 'undefined is not a function' error.

Comment: You need to post a link or make a jsfiddle. No enough info to help you

Comment: i tried to narrow down my question and include a codepen example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241945/how-to-correctly-append-items-to-masonry-js-in-this-example